# What is the meaning of "Mar"?

Tags: etymology, morphology, latin

I am wondering what is the meaning of ," Mar" part of some words such as Margarita, Maria, Martin?

I appreciate your answer!
Thanks in advance!

Margarita

Comment: I suggest that you look up the names in a **good** name book (e.g., A dictionary of first names by Hanks, Hardcastle and Hodges). You will see that there are different origins for the three names and there is no common meaning of Mar for them.

Answer (score 2):

It has no common meaning. *Margarita* is a Roman name, that word meant 'pearl' in Latin. *Martin* is also a Roman name, it comes from 'Mars', the name of the god of war. *Maria* is derived from the Hebrew name 'Miriam' (from the Ancient Egyptian 'beloved'), but later it combined with the Latin name 'Maria' which was the feminine form of 'Marius', both words probably derived from the Latin 'mare' - 'sea'. The Latin 'margarita' - 'pearl' - is a borrowing through Greek from a Middle Eastern language, [perhaps from Middle Persian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF#Etymology_2), but it's impossible to say for sure, since every Middle Eastern language seems to have that word to mean 'pearl'.